# sfValidatorSchemaCompare with own values?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorAnd(array(
      new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('email', '==', 'email_confirm',
            array(),
            array('invalid' => 'The email adresses must match')
          ),
      new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('password', '==', 'password_confirm',
            array(),
            array('invalid' => 'The passwords must match')
          ),
        )));
```

this compare two values from Form.
I would like make compare with own values:

```
    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('secret_key', '==', '123456',
            array(),
            array('invalid' => 'The secret key must match')
          ),

            How can i make it?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sfValidatorSchemaCompare`  compares the entered value in two fields (like in your first example).
For example: it tests if the `password` matches the `password_confirm` values. In this case both the `password` and `password_confirm` have to be fields in your form (validators to be exact).

In your case, you want to check if a `secret_key` matches a **predefined value**, **not** another field.
And this is a bit *strange*, by default symfony doesn't have a validator to check this. But you can easily use the `sfValidatorChoice` to achieve your target:

```
$this->validatorSchema['secret_key'] = new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array('123456')));
```

In this case the value entered in `secret_key` is matched against a list of values, which only contains your secret key.

And a little "pro-tip" ;-): Add the secret_key to your app.yml, and then just add `sfConfig::get('app_form_secret_key')` to test.